# Wordpress - Send message to users if function_exists by using Front End PM plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, email, author

I'm using the plugin "[Front End PM](https://wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-pm/)" and i have the snippet below for sending message to the frontend when authors posts is published, but not working for me and the error i get " unexpected '   ' (T_STRING) ", so the problem in between [' '] but i'm sorry i can't fix it.

```html
add_action( 'publish_post', 'fep_cus_user_publish_send_messaage', 10, 2 );

function fep_cus_user_publish_send_messaage( $ID, $post ){

    if ( ! function_exists( 'fep_send_message' ) )
    return;
    $message = [];
 
    $message['message_to_id'] = $post->post_author; /* Post author ID. */
    $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author );
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $permalink = get_permalink( $ID ); 
    $message['message_title'] = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $title );
    $message['message_content'] = sprintf ('Congratulations, %s! Your article “%s” has been published.' . "\n\n", $name, $title );
    $message['message_content'] .= sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink ); 
    $override = array('post_author' => 1, //change with message sender id         
    );

    // Send message
    fep_send_message( $message, $override );      
}
```

Comment: On which line do you receive the error? The log should tell you. I don't see any syntax errors in your snippet.

Comment: On this line `$message['message_to_id'] = $post->post_author;`

Comment: note: after removing the line i get err in the second line and so on!

Comment: That is interesting. I copied your snippet and there is strange undefined character behind `);`  Delete the whole line and rewrite that line again?

Comment: Ah you discovered it yourself. Have you copied the code from somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, i always copied any code into note first before inserting it in function.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your snippet in a proper text editor like [sublime text](https://www.sublimetext.com/), [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), [Vim](https://www.vim.org/) (just to name a few). Behind some lines you have characters that are copied from non well formatted code block from a site or from a tool that is not made for writing code. If you remove those characters your code will not generate a syntax error.

The snippet like this should work:

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'fep_cus_user_publish_send_messaage', 10, 2 );

function fep_cus_user_publish_send_messaage( $ID, $post ){

    if ( ! function_exists( 'fep_send_message' ) )
    return;
    $message = [];
 
    $message['message_to_id'] = $post->post_author; // Post author ID. 
    $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author );
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $permalink = get_permalink( $ID ); 
    $message['message_title'] = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $title );
    $message['message_content'] = sprintf ('Congratulations, %s! Your article “%s” has been published.' . '\n\n', $name, $title );
    $message['message_content'] .= sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink );
    $override = array('mgs_author' => 1);//change with message sender id  
    

    // Send message
    fep_send_message( $message, $override );      
}
```

EDIT: post_author was deprecated and removed. Use `mgs_author` instead.